# Google Sheets: Display value if date is between today and six months ago

Tags: google-sheets

I want to display "Just Trained" if my date field is between today and 6 months ago.

```
=IF(AND(P5 >= EDATE(today(),0), P5 <= Edate(today(),-6)), "Just Trained", 
    IF(AND(P5 >= edate(today(),-7), P5 <= edate(today(),-1000)), "", ""))
```

Not sure why this isn't working for me

Comment: Hello, if your question has been resolved, please mark this thread as "Answered". Also, please take this opportunity to take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and learn how to [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks), [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [Learn More](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)

Answer (score 1):

Try the formula below:

```
=IF(ISBETWEEN(P5,EDATE(TODAY(),-6),TODAY()),"Just Trained",)
```

This will show "Just Trained" if the date in cell P5 is between today, and six months before today (both inclusive). The final comma signifies that the formula will return a truly blank value when the date in cell P5 is not between the boundaries. A truly blank value is different from a zero-length text string `""`.

Comment: The two `datevalue()` calls are superfluous and can be left out. See [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/153275/269219) for an explanation why.

Comment: The datevalue() calls might be superfluous, but I would not recommend leaving them out. Often times, Google Sheets gets confused is dates are used and complex formulas will throw an Error. I have read the example, but I am speaking from experience.

Comment: In the formula given in the answer, `edate()` returns a dateserial value, and so does `today()`. The `datavalue()` wrappers add nothing. Will [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) the answer to make it simpler.